# Div zooming on iPhone rotation only in Safari on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, viewport

### The Issue

I am currently in the process of building a new responsive website. Everything seems to work great apart from one minor bug with Safari on IOS. When I rotate my device, one of my `div`'s is zooming in but **only** in Safari. Chrome on IOS works brilliantly!

My current viewport is set to ***(please note this works in everything apart from Safari on IOS )***:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
```

### What I have Tried

And I have tried the following ***(please note these solutions stop it from working in Chrome on IOS and my iPad)***:

1. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug
2. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/10/initialscale1_m.html
3. http://garybacon.com/post/viewport-bug-in-mobile-safari-on-iphone-and-ipad/

Any many other unsuccessful solutions...

### My Question

As this only seems to be happening with one `div` within my cotnent (the rest of the content does not zoom), my question is actually, what could be causing one element to zoom and others not? Is this to do with the viewport or could it be CSS?

I have compared my CSS between the working `div`'s and the one that zooms and I cannot see anything that stands out as the potential issue. Can anyone suggest anything?

*I have not included the code from my site as the site contents is confidential and removing all the components for example purposes could take a long time. If it is essential to see my full code then please say and I will do what I can to post up a relevant link*

### Example (Update)

Page loads correctly in portrait:

[image: Portrait Correct]

Page zooms on `div` when rotated:

[image: Landscape Error]

Page loads correctly in landscape if I **refresh**:

[image: Landscape Correct (after refreshed)]

Comment: Well...sorry but: No code example = not reproducable = no way to know what exactly you are writing about or what could be the reason for the problem... Please don't add the complete code of your complex website, but try to make a simple demo so others can help you, thank you.

Comment: @user1843159 See edit. Bottom line is, how do I prevent the phone from zooming when I rotate it?

Comment: Initial-scale=1 didn't work?

Comment: @user1843159 Negative, I have tried a combination of absolutely everything I can think of. What's weird is that all of the other `div`'s on the page are not zoomed in, and when I refresh the page, it fixes itself so I have a feeling it might be CSS on the particular `div` or an element within that `div`

Comment: Hard to guess... I can only suggest to remove all elements step by step to see what could be the reason. If all other content is ok, you should end up with only the code for the wrong behaving div - et voila you have a example you can post here ;) It could be because of wrong media queries or css sizes (px/em/rem...), a image in the div (pixel-image or vector-svg?), a background image with size cover or fixed, inherited values,... there can be many possible reasons...